# Why would there be too many memory accesses in my cache simulator?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

I have this code and I keep getting too many hits and too many misses. I am trying to create a cache simulator. I don't understand if the part where I see if it is a write is correct or not but also I do not understand why I am having too many memory accesses in general. Is this not the correct way to implement a direct mapped cache?

this is what I tried

```
def direct(self, index, tag, operation_size, address, offset, instruction):
            
            temp_address = address
            end_address = address + operation_size
            begin_index = self.get_index(temp_address)
            end_index = self.get_index(end_address)

            if begin_index < end_index:
                while begin_index <= end_index:
                    if self.cache_lines[begin_index] is None or self.cache_lines[begin_index] != tag:
                        self.misses += 1
                        if instruction == "W":
                            self.cache_lines[begin_index] = tag
                    else:
                        self.hits += 1
                    begin_index += 1
                #print(f"Crossed Line {index} address {bin(address)} at Index {index} size {bin(operation_size)} with accesses {num_crossed_lines +1}")
            elif end_index < begin_index:
                while begin_index < self.num_lines:
                    if self.cache_lines[begin_index] is None or self.cache_lines[begin_index] != tag:
                        self.misses += 1
                        if instruction == "W":
                            self.cache_lines[begin_index] = tag
                    else:
                        self.hits += 1
                    begin_index += 1
                x = 0
                new_tag = self.get_tag(end_address)
                while x <= end_index:
                    if self.cache_lines[x] is None or self.cache_lines[x] != new_tag:
                        self.misses += 1
                        if instruction == "W":
                            self.cache_lines[x] = new_tag
                    else:
                        self.hits += 1
                    x += 1

            else:
                if self.cache_lines[index] is None or self.cache_lines[index] != tag:
                    self.misses += 1
                    if instruction == "W":
                        self.cache_lines[index] = tag
                else:
                    self.hits += 1
```

I get
Cache hits:  14386766
Cache misses:  10048253

but I should have
Hits = 13,792,084
Misses = 9,557,030

sorry if this is confusing but I have no idea what I am doing wrong to get over a million too many memory accesses

Comment: Do you have access to detailed tracing of the one that works?  If so, make yours generate the same trace and compare to find first difference.  Otherwise, make a smaller test case to run on both, maybe start with a small case and make it larger (or a large case and make it smaller).  If you don't have either, not sure how you're going to proceed.

Comment: What does "W" mean and why update the cache line on miss *only if* "W"?